# How would you find the proportion of a value in an array

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to track down a way to find the proportion of a value in an array using numpy. For example, the proportion of values over 20 in this array:

```
array([1,3,4,20,40,50,3,5])
```

I used `np.size(array)` to get the array dimension (8 in this case), but am unsure how to get the number of elements that fulfill a certain condition.

Ideally, my endpoint is `(#number of True elements / np.size(array))`

Comment: `(x>20).sum()/len(x)`

Comment: `(x>20).mean()`

Comment: what do you mean by the proportion of a value?

Answer (score 0):

To find the proportion of values over 20 in your array, you can simply use - `('variable name' > 20).mean()`

Hope this helps. Happy coding!